# Remove all chunks except spawn and change world type (from default to amplified)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to play the latest version of Minecraft, with an amplified world, but I don't want to have to repeat all the time consuming work I have already done to get the things I have in my most recent established world (Elytra, rocket supply, shulker boxes, mending on everything etc.. you get the idea) So I am wondering if it is possible to take the save file/folder for a world in which I did all those things and...

- Remove all loaded chunks except the one(s) that have my farms and base in)
- Modify the world type from default to amplified

I have downloaded the latest version of MCEdit but it just crashes when I try to do almost anything.

I want to avoid cheating all of the good stuff in because that will remove all the fun and therefore any motivation to play,  but I don't want to repeat all of that work because the sheer amount of work/time it takes means there is a good change I will have lost interest by the time I have got it all.

So,  is what I want to do even possible?

Is there a way that works in 1.15.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to just have a go after piecing together a basic understanding from googling, and see what would happen.  Here's how I did it. (I'm not sure if each step is necesary or correct but it seems to have worked)

- Load the world.  Visit each thing I want to keep and place or remove a block (to force a save of that region)
- Close and save.
- Make a backup of the save folder (just in case)
- Delete ALL of the 'MCA' files in the 'regions' folder that don't have today's date on them (or all the ones that have a date older than the recent visit to the world)
- Using 'NBTexplorer' go into the `level.dat->data` folder and change 'generatorName' to 'amplified'  then save.

See from the picture below that it worked.

[image]

Comment: Using the "last modified" date, interesting idea. You could also just use F3 to see your coordinate and divide that by 512 to get the index of the region files. And for more precise changes, you need a program called "NBTExplorer", which can delete singe chunks.

Comment: I didn't know the divide by 512 thing. Thanks.  I'm tempted to redo my world but more precisely so that might come in handy.  I did use nbtexplorer but only to modify the world type from default to amplified.  I am new to it so lots to learn.  I would also like to learn how to 'reset' the end world like they do in Hermitcraft to refresh the end cities for new raids.

Comment: To reset the End, you simply delete everything in `DIM1`. If you want to keep the center island, keep `r.0.0.mca`, `r.0.-1.mca`, `r.-1.0.mca` and `r.-1.-1.mca`, that's up to 512 blocks away from the portal in all directions, putting the cutoff point right in the middle of the emptiness around it.